# JSON object value based on other object value

Tags: javascript, json

I need to find a value based on another object value

```
json = {[{ID:"1",city:"Atlanta"},{ID:"2",city:"New York"}]}
```

and so forth.

I need to find the value of a city where ID is x. Is there anyway to do it without using loops?

More Details:
I have to create a json object looping thru the document, then I send this json to the webservice, which return me another set of json to populate the fields.

Comment: Are there other properties, or is changing the JSON an option?

Comment: Why do you need to do this without using loops? is this thing massive? Also, are all id's guaranteed to be there? E.g. if you have something of id 5, is there guaranteed to be ids of 1-4. Lastly, are these things always in order? Meaning that the array comes pre-sorted by id?

Comment: Edited for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using JSONPath, JSONQuery, jLinq, etc...  although under-the-hood there's a very good chance they will use loops.

Answer (score 3):

You could format it as follows

```
var data = {
    id: "city",
    1: "Atlanta",
    2: "New York",
    6: "New Jersy",
    24: "San Diego"
};
```

At which point, access can be done using the ID and the array access operator

```
console.log(data[2], data[24]);
```

yields

> New York San Diego

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you store this like an array

```
array = ["Atlanta", "New York"];
```

Calling `array[0]` will return `"Atlanta"`.

If you have to use json you will need to use loops to do what you want.

Comment: This assumes that the ID's are in order, sequential, and start at 0.